# Does the maximum error when applying Taylors series decrease as $n$ increases? (Lagrange Form of the Remainder)

Tags: taylor-expansion

The title's kind of self explanatory
[image: 8]

In the Lagrange form of the remainder I intuitively know (though I'm not sure I'm right) that as $n$ increases, the maximum error would decrease since $n$ implies how many terms from the Taylor polynomials you use. And apparently the more terms you use to define a function at a certain point you will get a more accurate value.

1. Is my 'intuition' correct
2. Any ways to prove that? My intuition says I'm right, but no matter how hard I stare at the Lagrange thing, I can't figure out why that is so.

Comment: You know that the Taylor series centered at $c$ of a $C^\infty$ function doesn't converge necessarily to $f(x)$ when $x\ne c$, right?

Comment: Of course I just selected a random image on the internet turned out that wasn't the image I wanted. What I was going to find doesn't have that equal sign in it....

Comment: Just replaced with the image I wanted in the first place :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marty Cohen’s answer is correct, but I think more exposition is valuable. Especially since Runge’s Phenomenon isn’t about Taylor expansions exactly.

Indeed though, we may consider the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x^2}$ Consider taking the Taylor expansion around $0$. This Taylor expansion is given by:
$$P_k(x) = \sum_{n=0}^k (-1)^k \cdot x^{2k}$$
Now this Taylor series has a radius of convergence of 1. Let’s look at what happens outside that radius.

For ease of argumentation, let’s look at what happens at $x=2$ on the even-degree Taylor approximations. We know that $f(2) = \frac{1}{5}$. However, we may show that:
$$\begin{align*} |P_{2k}(2)| = | 1 - 2^2 + 2^4 - 2^6 + \cdots + (-1)^{2k} 2^{4k}| = \frac{1 + 4^{2k+1}}{5} \end{align*}$$
This expression is clearly increasing in $k$. It easily follows that as $k \rightarrow \infty$, we have that $P_{2k}(2) \rightarrow \infty$. Similar analysis shows that the Taylor approximation goes to $-\infty$ On the odd-degree Taylor approximations.

If you want to play around, I’ve prepared a Desmos file for you: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vloova1c1x

So in general, it is not true that the Taylor Remainder is decreasing.

When can we say for sure that the Taylor remainder is decreasing? Most notably, when the Taylor series is convergent to the function!

Answer (score 0):

Nope. A well-known example is
$\dfrac1{1+x^2}$
with uniformly spaced interpolation points
in $[-1, 1]$.

This is known as
Runge's phenomenon.

See
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon